# Return void from array.splice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have just started to learn angular4 and typescript. So, if this a very basic question then please forgive me.

In my angular service I am defining a method like:

```
  removePerson(person: Person): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve(PERSONS.splice(PERSONS.indexOf(person), 1));
  }
```

Compiler is complaining me that I should change the return type of function to `Promise<Person[]>` from `Promise<void>`

But I want to return void from that Promise. How can I change the body of my function?

Comment: splicing an array is synchronous...shouldn't need a promise here at all

Comment: @charlietfl I want to use promises because after splicing the array I should get notified that element was removed from the array and so, I can use array for other purposes.]

Comment: [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) returns a Promise.

Comment: @mhodges then how can I remove element from array?

Comment: *"should get notified"* ... it is synchronous....you are overthinking it.

Comment: *after splicing the array I should get notified that element was removed* - not sure what this should mean. If the method is synchronous, you can call it with `removePerson(...)` and be sure that right after that the element was removed.

Comment: `splice` is destructive. It will splice the element(s) out of the array and pass them to the function invoked by `Promise.resolve()` - if any. But your removePerson function itself is returning a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it should be

```
function removePerson(person: Person): Promise<void> {
  PERSONS.splice(PERSONS.indexOf(person), 1);
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

`removePerson` is synchronous and the promise does nothing here. If there's no real reason for it to return a promise (e.g. the class implements existing API where `removePerson` should return a promise), it may be changed to

```
function removePerson(person: Person): void {
  PERSONS.splice(PERSONS.indexOf(person), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

returning "void" in javascript means don't return any thing like this:

```
 removePerson(person:Person){
    PERSONS.splice(PERSONS.indexOf(person), 1);
 }
```

Comment: That should work great but I am trying to learn Promises, so can you please help?

Comment: I would suggest you to search google about angular 2 and observables, you will find many tutorials for that.(You need promises if you need to wait for result (like from server)).